# Syntax Error When Trying to Save Workbook in openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, syntax-error, openpyxl

I'm attempting to write probabilities into an excel file using openpyxl. For some reason, I'm getting a syntax error when I try to save the workbook. Please help.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
import math

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

for m in range(1,50):
    for n in range(1,50):
        firstTo1 = m
        firstTo2 = n
        maxPoints = (2 * firstTo1 - 1) * (2 * firstTo2 - 1)
        maxPoints1 = 2 * firstTo1 - 1
        maxPoints2 = 2 * firstTo2 - 1
        probSum1 = 0.0
        tempProb1 = 0.0
        probSum2 = 0.0
        tempProb2 = 0.0
        winDec = 0.55
        r = firstTo1
        for y in range(firstTo1, maxPoints1 + 1):
            tempProb1 = (math.factorial(y-1) / (math.factorial((y-1)-(r-1)) * math.factorial(r-1))) * (winDec**r) * ((1-winDec)**(y-r))
            probSum1 += tempProb1
        r = firstTo2
        for y in range(firstTo2, maxPoints2 + 1):
            tempProb2 = (math.factorial(y-1) / (math.factorial((y-1)-(r-1)) * math.factorial(r-1))) * (probSum1**r) * ((1-probSum1)**(y-r))
            probSum2 += tempProb2           
        c = sheet.cell(row = n+2, column = m+2)
        c.value = probSum2
        
wb.save('CapstoneData.xlsx')
```

Running this code block gives this error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 23
    wb.save('CapstoneData.xlsx')
    ^^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Because there are no errors before I save the workbook, I don't quite understand where the error is from. I have already verified the validity of my calculations, just need to write them into Excel. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Do not you have some invisible characters on the last two lines? Try to delete them and write the last command again. --- Also please show how exactly do you run the script, not just the error output. --- Note: You do not need `from openpyxl import Workbook` because you use only the full name: `wb = openpyxl.Workbook()`

Comment: The traceback is incomplete but the code runs fine so you have not copied it correctly.

Comment: @pabouk-Ukrainestaystrong Thank you. I retyped the last 2 lines and it worked.